# How do I get distinct fields from MongoRepository/QueryDSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, querydsl

My Document is

```
@QueryEntity @Data @Document(collection = "MyCol") public class MyCol {
    @Id private String _id;
    private     String version;
```

I want to get all distinct version stored in the db.

My attempts:

```
public interface MyColDao extends MongoRepository<MyCol, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyCol> {
    @Query("{ distinct : 'MyCol', key : 'version'}")
    List<String> findDistinctVersion();
}
```

Or just findDistinctVersion without the query annotation.

Most of the examples of github have a By-field like

```
  List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
```

I don't need a By field.

Another example I found [here](https://github.com/rgrbev/Twitchable/blob/302b1066c5be8293ad3aae8904df8e348957f1f8/src/main/java/com/twitchable/project/repository/ChannelRepository.java).

```
@Query("{ distinct : 'channel', key : 'game'}")
public JSONArray listDistinctGames();
```

This doesn't seem to work for me.

I can't seem to find queryDSL/Morphia's documentation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I couldn't work out how to do it within the `MongoRepository` (as far as I can tell, it's not currently possible) so ended up using `MongoTemplate` instead.

I believe the following would meet your requirement.

```java
@AutoWired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate

public List<String> getVersions(){
    return mongoTemplate.findDistinct("version", MyCol.class, String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public interface MyColDao extends MongoRepository<MyCol, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyCol> {
        @Query("{'yourdbfieldname':?0}")
        List<String> findDistinctVersion(String version);
    }
```

here version replaces your your db field name 
more you can [see here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-mongodb/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was trying to fetch a list of all versions are not a specific version. Will this code do that?

Comment: I am also looking for the same. If you found it could you add it as an answer? I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This spring documentation provide the details, how to form a expression when you are want to fetch distinct values.

[Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)